# Could IPSec flows be decrypted using PSK

Tags: ipsec

I created an IPSec tunnel between two VMs using StrongSwan. It relies on a Pre-Shared Key. I wonder, if this key is leaked, what could an attacker perform?
Would he/she be able to decrypt previous exchanges?
Could he/she perform a MITM without be detected? 
And more generally, what is the impact?

Some details:

- Mode Tunnel
- auth-trunc hmac(sha256)
- enc cbc(aes)